# explain limit computing result

Tags: calculus, limits

I got the following limit result via [Mathematica](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim_%28x-%3E-oo%29x%5E%281%2Fx++%29), anyone can show why the result it is ?

$\lim_{{{x}\to-\infty}}{x}^{{\frac{{1}}{{x}}}}=1$

The last term in the following transformation require $x>0$，while $x<0$ in the process ${x}\to-\infty$ , so this way cannot work.

$\lim_{{{x}\to-\infty}}{x}^{{\frac{{1}}{{x}}}}=\lim_{{{x}\to-\infty}}{e}^{ \ln{{\left({x}^{{\frac{{1}}{{x}}}}\right)}}}=\lim_{{{x}\to-\infty}}{e}^{{\frac{ \ln{{x}}}{{x}}}}$

P.S.1) I am considering the limit in extended real number system.

2)someone says we could do like this : let -t = x, then 
$\lim_{{{t}\to\infty}}-{t}^{{\frac{{1}}{ -{{t}}}}}=\lim_{{{t}\to\infty}}-{1}^{{\frac{{1}}{ -{{t}}}}}\cdot{t}^{{\frac{{1}}{ -{{t}}}}}={\left(-{1}\right)}^{{0}}\cdot\lim_{{{t}\to\infty}}{e}^{ \ln{{\left({t}^{{\frac{{1}}{ -{{t}}}}}\right)}}}={1}$

is it right ?

Comment: This limit is not well posed since $x^{\frac{1}{x}}$ is defined only for $x >0$.

Comment: How do you define, e.g., $(-\pi)^{-\frac1\pi}$?

Comment: @Crostul function has limt seems doesn't require the function to be continuous ,e.g. the limit of a sequence.

Comment: @iMath I didn't say anything about continuity. My point is that $-\infty$ is not a limit point of the domain of the function, so it is meaningless to ask what is this limit.

Comment: @Crostul How do you know −∞ is not a limit point of the domain of the function ?

Comment: You can use the lhospitals rule

Comment: @Crostul the domain of f(x) NOT containing any interval of the form (a,oo) or (-oo,a) for any possible value of a doesn't mean  one cannot compute  the limit of f(x), e.g.the limit of a sequence, sequence is also another type of function .

Answer (score 1):

Let us first consider the given limit as $L$.

$$L=\lim_{x\to(-\infty)}x^{\frac{1}{x}}=\lim_{x\to(-\infty)}\exp\left(\ln\left(x^{\frac{1}{x}}\right)\right)=\lim_{x\to(-\infty)}\exp\left(\frac{\ln x}{x}\right)=\exp\left(\lim_{x\to(-\infty)}\left(\frac{\ln x}{x}\right)\right)$$

But we don't have any defined limit for $\dfrac{\ln x}{x}$ when $x\to(-\infty)$ even though W|A says otherwise. The reason is that we get complex values when you consider the complex natural logarithm and there is no limit since we aren't dealing with reals now.

If it was $x\to\infty$, then we can easily say that since $x$ grows faster than $\ln x$, we have the limit as $e^0=1$.

But, for $x\to(-\infty)$, there is no valid limit, in my opinion.

Comment: I am considering the limit in extended real number system.

Comment: @iMath, I still don't think that a finite limit exists.

Comment: You can let $y=-x$, that could simplify a little bit.

Comment: @GohP.iHan, that will make $\ln(x)=\ln(-y)~,~y\to\infty$ which still has no defined real value. We can try to make it look prettier but the conclusion remains the same, in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow +\infty}\frac{\log{x}}{x}=0$$

So

$$\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow +\infty}e^{\frac{\log{x}}{x}}=1$$

And as in the comment $x^{\frac{1}{x}}=e^{\frac{\log{x}}{x}}$

Comment: Note that the OP has $x\to (-\infty)$ **not** $x\to\infty$

Comment: $x^{1/x}$ is not defined for $x\leq 0$

Comment: Yes, I know that. But I guess the OP doesn't know that.

Comment: Or is it a typo don't you think ?

Comment: @PrasunBiswas From my perspective ,both x→(−∞) and x→∞ – all mean x tends to negative infinity

Comment: @marwalix not defined for all negative numbers , but defined for some, e.g. x=-3

Comment: @iMath, as Sir Hagen said earlier in the comments, it depends on how you define it. As a different example, $-(-1)^{1/3}$ can either be $1$ or $-e^{\frac{i\pi}{3}}$ depending on how you define it.

Comment: @PrasunBiswas I am considering the limit in extended real number system.